# How do I aggregate SQL data (e-mail events) to reduce number of records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation**:

- I'm continuously storing e-mail event data (opens, clicks, unsubscribes, etc.) from my e-mail campaigns.
- I have sent over 82 million emails this year, and many e-mails to the same person (which leads to my next point).
- I am concerned that using a row for each event (opens, for example) is inefficient.

**Question**: What might be a better way to organize the data? Is there a way to aggregate the event data for each contact/person in a single row, and still allow SQL to access each event/property?

Here's how I might envision storing the data:

[image]

But then again, I would like the data to be handle by Microsoft SQL, rather than by PHP, and I'm not sure how that can be done.  Any insight would be helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Isn't a database made to store a lot of data? Using it as intended, with a single row per event, seems much more efficient to me than storing different events in text fields as shown and having to parse the JSON every time you want to query it. How will you answer questions like "how many people have clicked campaign XXX?" otherwise?

Comment: I guess I expect that the number of records will eventually grow into the billions, and it's difficult for me to see it efficient to run tests on such large tables. Your second question really hits the nail on the head though. Yeah, it wouldn't really be very feasible to find out how many people clicked on campaign "XXX".

Comment: After reading your question and a very good comment from CompuChip, I would suggested looking into  SQL Server table partitioning (Costs money as only available in Enterprise Edition) but you really are dealing with huge amount of data here, 82 million rows in one year , by the end of next year you will be dealing with almost 150 rows , I think Table Partitioning will help you a lot.

Comment: Partitioning seems like the thing to do in my case. I probably won't worry about that until the table gets a little larger.

Comment: What database do you use? Mysql or ms sql? Because solutions could very well be vendor specific for such large tables!

Comment: As I mentioned, MS SQL.

Comment: Have you done any performance testing with a much larger number of rows?  What would characterize unacceptable performance for you if there were, say, a billion rows in your table?  Are you sure that you have properly identified opportunities to place indexes on your table?

Comment: @DavidTansey, this is the first time I've dealt with this many rows.  I'll probably put them in a single table, maybe I'll extend it out to a billion or two and do some performance testing. Testing performance on a SQL server is something relatively new to me, so I haven't really determined what is unacceptable.  I'd say that indexing could be done on contact_id (if it were unique/primary, which it's not currently because there are duplicate events regarding that person).  Otherwise, the date of the event could be something to index.

Comment: If you need to log the specific parameters that surround an event (for example, the date/time that an email was viewed or clicked-through) then you will need to have a record for each event.

By normalising your data structure effectively, you can manage the data effectively, and minimise the size of your database.  For example, you don't need to record the entire email content for each click event, you would have a mail message table, a recipient table, an instance table (many-to-many link of mail to recipient) and an activity table that records activity type (say "click") and date/time. HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe normalize your Database creating 2 tables for this Job.

One  for Master data (Client/Person data), and another to Details (Clicks Views)

Something like this
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO8Fn.jpg)